# Смена состояние Toggle Button и обновление Seekbar в Mediaplayer

Tags: java, android, mediaplayer

Приветствую.

Я сделал `selector`

```
  <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_action_play" />
<item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_action_pause" />
```

Затем назначил его `background`-ом в `togglebutton`

```
   <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/play"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:textOn=""
            android:textOff=""
            android:text=""
            android:background="@drawable/play_pause"
            android:contentDescription="@string/play" />
```

Затем в своем `activity` прописал следующий код

```
public class HeadsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

      MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
      Handler handler;
      SeekBar seekBar;
      ToggleButton play, replay;
      int length = 0;

   @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_heads);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    handler = new Handler();
    play = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.play);
    replay = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.replay);
    seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seek);
    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.my_sound);
    length = mediaPlayer.getDuration();
    seekBar.setMax(length);
    handler.postDelayed(my_UpdateTimeTask, 100);
    seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean input) {
            if(mediaPlayer != null && input) {
                mediaPlayer.seekTo(progress);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }
    });

    play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(play.isChecked()) {
                mediaPlayer.start();
            } else {
                mediaPlayer.pause();
            }
        }
    });

   replay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(replay.isChecked()) {
                mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
            } else {
                mediaPlayer.setLooping(false);
            }
        }
    });
 }

   private Runnable my_UpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            int my_CurrentPosition = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
            seekBar.setProgress(my_CurrentPosition);
        } try {
            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};
```

Теперь, когда я воспроизожу аудио, `togglebutton` из состояния `play`, переключается в состояние `pause` и в этом все работает отлично, и также `seekbar` передвигается в соответствии с аудио файлом. Но проблема в том, что когда аудио заканчивается, `togglebutton` не переключает свое состояние, и остается во втором состоянии `pause`, и нужно нажать раз, только потом переключается в состояние `play` и нажав второй раз только тогда аудио воспроизводится вновь. Вопрос: Как мне по завершению аудио сменить состояние `togglebutton` и как скинуть на ноль состояние линии `seekbar` `progress`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте к своему медиаплееру

```
mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
    //Метод вызывается, когда трек заканчивается
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        //TODO : переключение состояния кнопки
    }
});
```

подробнее почитайте в документации

Comment: Рабоает! Состояние `togglebutton` сменяется, я просто прописал в методе `onCompletion` `play.setChecked(false);`

Comment: @McDaggen поздравляю) В дальнейшем, если у вас возникнет необходимость обработки и других состояний вашего медиаплеера, загляните в документацию, там много лисенеров для различных состояний. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html

Comment: Также я обнулил значение `seekbar` пописав там же                 `seekBar.setProgress(0);` если кому-то вдруг понадобится.